# If i add more memory for hardware (hardware reserved) will the perfomace boost a little bit?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, memory, dell-precision

**At the moment it is just 150 of hardware reserved, if i make it like 2gb will there be difference is the question?**

32GB ram
Intel HD Graphics 630 (128 vram)
and Quadro M2200 (4gb vram) working at the same time
i7-7820HQ

i mean, its more than enough, but can I get even more?

Comment: It all depends on what you need it for. Sorry, but no answer is really possible here.

Comment: all i need to know is there a difference

Comment: For some operations, yes. For others, no. We can't tell which are yours.

Comment: mainly for multitasking and video games

Comment: @MartoxD - Increase the amount of memory your iGPU has access to will not resolve any performance problems in any application that uses your Quadro.  The only way to resolve performance problems with your Quadro is to replace it with a better card.  **Your iGPU is significantly worse than your Quadro  anyways due to the low amount  VRAM it has access to (2 GB).**

Comment: igpu not used for games anyway, thanks for the information!